# Can a JavaScript ternary operator support 3 conditions?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, ternary-operator, ternary

Given the following JavaScript ternary operator, is it possible to enable this to support 3 conditions versus the current two?

```
const color = d.y >= 70 ? "green" : "red";
```

I would essentially like the following logic:

```
>= 70, color = green;
between 69-50, color = yellow;
< 50, color = red;
```

Is this possible with a 1 line ternary or do I need a IF statement?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

you can do

```
const color = d.y >= 70 ? "green" : (d.y < 50 ? "red" : "yellow");
```

Comment: What do the brackets represent?

Answer (score 12):

you can stack it like this:

```
condition1 
  ? result1 
  : condition2 ? result3 : result4
```

Answer (score 6):

Just have a second ternary operator:

```
const color = d.y >= 70 ? "green" : d.y >= 50 ? "yellow" : "red";
```